# CSS Animation: Changing The Background Color

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following style block:

```css
@keyframes flip {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    background-color: UNKNOWN;
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0);
  }
}
```

For the animation to work nicely, I need to change the background color at `50%`. The problem is that some JavaScript function will decide what that color should be. Is accessing the stylesheet with JavaScript my only option to deal with such a case?

### Edit

---

Suppose I have three objects next to each other, and they independently obtain their color through some JavaScript function. How does CSS `var()` deal with that?

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) with a default defined in your `:root` css, and using Javascript to set a new value

---

Demo were the initial value of `--background-color` is `orange`, then after 2 seconds we use Javascript to alter it to `blue`

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const e = document.querySelector('.animate');
  e.style.setProperty('--background-color', 'blue');
}, 2000);
```

```css
:root {
    --background-color: orange;
}

@keyframes flip {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    background-color: var(--background-color);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0);
  }
}

.animate {
  animation: flip 5s infinite;
  
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="animate" />
```